# WSO2 IS - Active Directory Login - Not working correctly

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have attached my Active Directory as a secondary user store and can see the list of users when i select "Users" however when accessing an APP through tomcat that is linked to SAML SSO i cannot login using an AD Account

can anyone suggest what i am missing?

the error in the system logs is

`TID[-1234] [IS] [2014-02-13 13:49:02,321] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator} - user authentication failed due to invalid credentials.`

however my login credentials are correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because i was using email address as a login that was causing the issue!

the steps i took are as follows:

IS_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml file.

- Open carbon.xml
- Locate EnableEmailUserName element and uncomment it.
- Finally, it should be similar to the following 
  true
- Now, restart IS

You should be able to login using your user name

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether you can login to WSO2 management console using above credentials. If you can not,  please go to  Management Console -> Configure -> Users and Roles -> Roles  and you can see the internal\everyone role.  And configure "login" permission for everyone role. Then please try to login...

Also, if you enable the debug logs in  `org.wso2.carbon.user.core`, you can see more debug logs about authentication failure.

Comment: Yea i cannot login, to the console either, already set the login box for the "Everyone" role will add the debug and report the latest message.

Comment: So i am login in using my email address, will this cause issues?

the error i am getting now is as follows:

User: james.tyreman exist: false

the user should be my email address though not just my name...

Comment: so may be your AD configurations that you added in the WSO2IS is wrong... Please check the "UserNameSearchFilter" value.. If you are login with email,  it mus be  "(&amp;(objectClass=person)(email=?))"  If you use CN  it must be (&amp;(objectClass=person)(cn=?))...

Comment: it was userPrincipleName, so put all these settings in  the user-mgt.xml file, and getting this error when starting the server:

[Fatal Error] :143:7: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]"
is not allowed.
[2014-02-13 15:16:39,135] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -
  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in building Document
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getConfiguration
Element(DefaultRealmService.java:268)

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration is not ok.same login issue already solved here.[cannot login to wso2 Identity server with the ldap credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062834/cannot-login-to-wso2-identity-server-with-the-ldap-credentials/20066689#20066689).
Make sure UserDNPattern property  is correct