# Active Directory Login fails in Single Sign On

Tags: authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using **SAML 2.0 Web browser based SSO** using WSO2 Identity Server.
In which I have configured Active Directory as a Secondary user store.

Users in **Active directory** are getting listed in management UI, however they are not getting authenticated at one of my Service Provider.

Following is the configuration which I have done in Identity server according to my Active Directory Setup.

[image: Main Conguration]

[image: Optional Configuration]

Every time I try to login using user credentials, authentication goes fail.
Following is the error stack:

> TID: [0] [IS] [2015-04-28 12:18:51,736] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   -  Authentication failed for user deepv {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2015-04-28 12:18:51,736] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   -  Authentication Failed {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator}
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Authentication Failed     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:114)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) TID: [0] [IS] [2015-04-28
>   12:18:51,738] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler}
>   -  Authentication Failed {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler}
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Authentication Failed     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth.BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.java:115)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultRequestPathBasedSequenceHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:114)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745).

I tried using different **objectClass** for user which are possible according to my directory structure. e.g inetOrgPerson, person, user etc.

But still I am not able to authenticate the users.

I am using WSO2 Identity server 5.0.0 with **BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator** for providing the user credentials at Service provider, not to Identity provider Login page.

I tried this without BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator, but still users are not authenticated.

I found similar question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755781/wso2-is-active-directory-login-not-working-correctly) link. But it did not worked for me as I am authenticating the users using **sAMAccountName** parameter, not using **Emailid**.

I need some guidance on this as I might have missed something important that needs to be done. Please help If someone have faced this Issue.

Thanks..

Comment: Are you getting this for all Service providers or only for some Service providers

Comment: I have list of 3 service providers. And I got this for all service providers.

Comment: Can u login to Identity server management console with those users.

Comment: I can. But for that to happen I have to go to the every user, give it to permission of login in internal/everyone role, then after only I am able to login using that user credential only.
I did the same integration of my LDAP directory with IS, but all LDAP users are by default having login permission in internal/everyone role.
So SSO using LDAP implementation is working for IS + SP both.

Comment: By default internal/everyone won't get login permission (even for LDAP). What you have to do it go to roles and assign permission for internal everyone.
After giving permission they should be able to login

Comment: I am getting login permission by default for all LDAP (Read only)
users.