# WSO 2 Identity Server LDAP settings do not work

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Since LDAP configuration is not trivial I would like to try connection and if possible list users or something.

I set the secondary user store as ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager and the settings but I cannot login with any user from LDAP (it is actually an AD server).

I checked the logs (TRACE level) but found nothing.

Also - jut a thought - do I have to do something to enable secondary user store or tell WSO2IS to actually use it or is it automatic? Just wondering that the reason for lack of logs is caused by this and it has nothing to do with LDAP settings.

EDIT: After creating the AD user store this exception gets written into the log:

```
[2014-12-08 15:10:57,535] ERROR -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.createSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3478)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3534)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager.deploy(UserStoreDeploymentManager.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.deploy(UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java:58)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext.<init>(LDAPConnectionContext.java:87)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:150)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
    ... 25 more
[2014-12-08 15:10:57,551]  INFO -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The deployment of apibp.xml is not valid. {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your configuration .You can refer this link [cannot login to wso2 Identity server with the ldap credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062834/cannot-login-to-wso2-identity-server-with-the-ldap-credentials/20066689#20066689). It may help you

Comment: He "succeeded in the integration and could access ldap users from wso2 identity server" but I can't even do that.

Comment: OMG, the port was missing from the config, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly configured a LDAP userstore, you could be able to see following logs

```
[2014-12-08 14:32:56,160]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2014-12-08 14:32:56,162]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager} -  Realm configuration of tenant:-1234  modified with /home/abimaran/support-issues/MINISTRYIEPROD/wso2is-4.6.0/repository/deployment/server/userstores/WSO2_TEST.xml
```

And, if you can't connect LDAP from Identity server, you will have some exception in the logs.

Comment: I've edited my question with the exception after user store creation. Nothing else is in the log. Also when I try to log in: nothing. I tried with log level DEBUG but nothing that seems related to the problem.